# Unable to fetch Recordtype picklist values dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, record-type

I am trying to build below VF page,PFA.I want to fetch those picklist values dynamically without hardcoding. I need to assign VF page to one of the record type. and rest all should navigate to standard page. Basically i am overriding New button so that i can assign the record type to VF page,Inorder to that i created below page.

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" e>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">

        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<p>
    Select a record type for the new opportunity. To skip this page in the future, change your record type settings on your personal setup page.
        </p>
        <br/> 
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Opportunity Record Type">
           <apex:selectList  label="Record Type of new record" value='{!Opportunity.recordtype.pick}'>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOptions}" />
            </apex:selectList>           
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class NewExtension {

    public Opportunity Opp{get;set;}
    public string pick{get;set;}

    public NewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {

        Opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {
        RecordType rt;
        rt = [Select Id,DeveloperName From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'Opportunity'];

        if(pick == 'PM-I Opportunity' &&  rt.DeveloperName == 'PM_I_Opportunity' )
        {
        return new PageReference('/apex/OppExtension');
        }   
        else

        return new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType='+rt.id+'&ent=Opportunity');
    }
   public PageReference Cancel()
   {
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
   }


 public List<SelectOption> getTypeOptions(){
          List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
          List<RecordTypeInfo> rtinf = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();
           for (RecordTypeInfo rtf : rtinf) 
           {
                   if(rtf.isAvailable() && rtf.getName() ) 
{                
                  options.add(new SelectOption(rtf.getRecordTypeId() , rtf.getName()));   
               return options;

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently `pick` is null. You need to assign the recordtype value before using it.

```
public PageReference save()
    {
        RecordType rt;
        rt = [Select Id,DeveloperName From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'Opportunity'];
        pick = Opp.recordtype.LC_FPD_PR_Opportunity;

        if(pick == 'PM-I Opportunity' &&  rt.DeveloperName == 'PM_I_Opportunity' )
        {
            return new PageReference('/apex/OppExtension');
        }   
        else

        return new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType='+rt.id+'&ent=Opportunity');
    }
```

Comment: @Derek I have added the List<selectOption> method and used the same in VF.  Error- no viable alternative at character ' ' in for loop. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch recordTypes through SObject describe information like so

```
// This brief example uses getRecordTypeInfosById(), but you could also use
//   getRecordTypeInfosByName().
// Predictably, if you use getRecordTypeInfosByName(), the key of the resulting map
//   is a String, rather than an Id
Map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recTypes = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
```

The one real 'gotcha' to this method is that the 'name' that you can get from the `RecordTypeInfo` class is the label (not the developer name).

If you'll just be using this to generate data for an `<apex:selectList>`, you could simply use `getRecordTypeInfos()` to get a List of record type info records, and loop over them to generate your `SelectOption` records.